# WordPress JSON API: Retrieve multiple posts by ids

Tags: arrays, json, wordpress, rest

I am using the WordPress JSON API plugin with my website. https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api/

I'm attempting to retrieve multiple posts, by their ids through a REST call.

For example:
    http://www.example.org/api/core/get_posts/?posts__in=7742,20715

According to the plugin documentation, get_posts supports all parameters of the WP_QUERY function, so this should work. However, this call returns

```
{
  "status": "ok",
  "count": 0,
  "count_total": 0,
  "pages": 0,
  "posts": [

  ],
  "query": {
    "ignore_sticky_posts": true,
    "post__in": "7742,20715"
  }
}
```

Note that the posts aren't returned. However, I have verified these post ids to be valid and correct.

Am I calling the json api incorrectly?

Thank you,

William

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you can fetch by IDs by use simple code:

```
http://demo.wp-api.org/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?include=1,35
```

Comment: Old post, but would be nice if this is the accepted answer.

Answer (score 6):

It is possible to fetch only some posts by id by passing `include[]` with API v2:

```
http://demo.wp-api.org/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?include[]=496&include[]=503
```

I've tried it and it works.

Source: https://github.com/WP-API/WP-API/issues/1368#issuecomment-290136087

Answer (score 0):

From a quick look at the source code, it looks like this is not supported:

Line 46 of `query.php`

```
$wp_translation = array(
  'json' =>           'json',
  'post_id' =>        'p',
  'post_slug' =>      'name',
  'page_id' =>        'page_id',
  'page_slug' =>      'name',
  'category_id' =>    'cat',
  'category_slug' =>  'category_name',
  'tag_id' =>         'tag_id',
  'tag_slug' =>       'tag',
  'author_id' =>      'author',
  'author_slug' =>    'author_name',
  'search' =>         's',
  'order' =>          'order',
  'order_by' =>       'orderby'
);
```

I also need this functionality, so when I get a chance I'll write some code for adding this and post it here.